# Suppress poly-fill provided by babel

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Is there a way to suppress the polyfill provided by babel? For example, transpiling the following:

```
const obj = { a: 1 };
const obj2 = { ...obj };
```

Will output

```
var _extends = Object.assign || function (target) { for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) { var source = arguments[i]; for (var key in source) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) { target[key] = source[key]; } } } return target; };

var obj = { a: 1 };
var obj2 = _extends({}, obj);
```

I would like it to output:

```
var obj = { a: 1 };
var obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj);
```

Due to the nature of our code-base, I would like to provide an Object.assign polyfill and then have babel not make this transform when it transpiles. I've read through the docs, and can't find a way to make this happen. Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you want that? The babel way is bulletproof..

Comment: As long as your `Object.assign` polyfill executes first, then `_extends` will use your polyfill. I don't really see a problem. If there is a problem, then clearly explain what it is and why you want to suppress Babel's behavior.

Comment: It may seem silly, but we transpile each file of our codebase individually (I agree this is ridiculous). So if I'm loading 10 js files on one page then this transform will show up 10 times. So it's a matter of adding weight to file rather than the actual execution of the file.

Comment: Babel has utilities to avoid injecting the helpers into every file file, FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the [object rest spread transform plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/). As noted by the documentation, it can be configured to just use built in functions rather than providing it's own polyfill. If you're using a `.babelrc` to configure your build process, you can simply modify it to something like this:

```
{
  ...
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-object-rest-spread", { "useBuiltIns": true }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much - can't believe I missed this in the docs!